# Program type already present: android.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap$1

Tags: android

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: D:\AndroidStudioProjects\GameTest\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\GameTest\app\build\intermediates\transforms\externalLibsDexMerger\debug\0, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\GameTest\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\32.jar, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\GameTest\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\GameTest\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\GameTest\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\GameTest\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\GameTest\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\GameTest\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\GameTest\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\GameTest\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, D:\AndroidStudioProjects\GameTest\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar

[image]

Comment: add your build.gradle

Comment: screenshot of your build.gradle file

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented one project `gate rusher-debug`

Open `build.gradle` of that project and check which appcompat version they have used.

Try to make it same.

You are getting errors because they are conflicting with version.